# How to position div table lower from the top?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<body>

 <div id="container">
 <div id="body">
<center>
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="40"><img src="logo.jpg" alt=" Store" width="100" height="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20" align="center" class="intro"> <a href="">online store</a> | <a href="">main website</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="352" align="center"><img src="str.jpg" width="500" height="500"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </center>
  </div>

  <!-- Ola sto span class mporoun na xwresoun? -->
 <div id="footer" class="intro"><span style class="bottom">  email | the store | address | tel   </div>
 </div>


</body>
```

The table is now in the center of the browser. The thing I wanna change is not to start from the very top, I want the table to be a little lower, for example 30 pixels from the top.

Ok well I made the whole table go lower by adding `<br>` before the `<table>` tag but this is ridiculous. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<br>` is perfect way to lower the table down. Although you can do it with CSS styles which will give you more precise movement.I typically use padding

```
#mytable {
padding-top:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a margin on it with the style attribute:

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="margin-top: 100px;">
```

You could also use a percentage value, eg:

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="margin-top: 20%;">
```

Comment: well that works, but my footer goes also down, which mean it adds you know, a scrollbar at the right and I dont want that. I want it only 1 page